# AJAX serialized data empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post form data via AJAX.

When I remove the AJAX function and do a standard form POST method the data is being inserted into DB fine. When I `console.log` the serialized data of the form on submit it shows fine.

It's when the AJAX function is fired that the data seemingly disappears. The function fires as a success but no data is inserted and the formdata variable is seemingly empty. Can anyone shine any light on this?

Here's the code so far -

**jQuery/AJAX -**

```
$('#calendar-form').submit(function() {
  var formdata = $(this).serialize();
  console.log(formdata);
  $.ajax({
    url: "insert.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    success: function() {
      alert('success')
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('ERROR');
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="calendar-form" action="" method="" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="hidden" name="site" id="site" value="<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>">
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
try {
    $bd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=;charset=utf8", "", "");
        //  $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATT_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Theres been an error while attempting to connect to the database';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $site = $_POST['site'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `users`(`name`, `email`, `site`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$site')";

        try {
            $query = $bd->prepare($sql);
            $query->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindValue(':site', $site, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if($query->execute()){
                echo "Success";
            }else{
                echo "Failure";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Note: I've removed DB details for this post but they're there in code.

**Console**

name=Benji&email=email%40email.com&site=localhost%3A8888 - scripts.min.js:9:117

**Network**

[image: Console - Network]

Comment: You are not using prepared statements properly.. Use placeholders as values.. Don't throw post data inside

Comment: Can you take a look at the Network tab of your developers tool to analyse that request?

Comment: What does a print_r($_POST); Return?

Comment: console.log(formdata); => console.debug(formdata); What's the output for this in the console?

Comment: @OfirBaruch Network is looking fine there's a 200 status on post method with the insert.php. all scripts and css is being included too.

Comment: @Akintunde I realise the PHP is not comprehensive, I'm only at the start of development and my main focus right now is to get the AJAX working and posting to DB. If I take the AJAX functionality out and use a standard post method on the form that runs the PHP it inserts data to the database no problem.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Also console debug output is "name=Benji%20Huggins&email=email%40email.com&site=localhost%3A8888"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because jQuery's `.serialize()` [does not include the submit button](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button.

Check the console for the output of your `console.log(formdata)` - you'll see `submit` is missing.  And since it is missing, the test you do on that value on the back end will fail:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

Exactly how to do solve this depends on what you're trying to do.  If you just want to make sure the request was a POST (not a GET) you could use:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
```

If you want to do basic validation, you could explicitly check each of the expected values are present:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['site'])) {
```